# request multipart/form-data req.body vacio

Tags: php

como están?

Estoy trabajando sobre la libreria de whaticket (https://github.com/canove/whaticket) y lo que requiero es hacer llegar un whatsapp con algún archivo media. La libreria ya está preparada para eso.

El problema está en que, al realizar el request por postman, funciona, llega la imagen correctamente, pero al escribirlo en el código, junto al formulario, el request llega vacio.

Este es el CURL PHP que me da Postman:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://localhost:8080/api/messages/send',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('number' => '5491130830111','medias'=> new CURLFILE('/C:/Users/jbermolen/Downloads/12.png'),'body' => 'Mensaje de prueba'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer 6adfa67b-94cd-4a49-b171-7d961a06c472',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

En el controlador, al recibir la petición, imprimo el req.body y me devuelve el número de celular -> number y el mensaje -> body.
Al hacerlo desde el siguiente archivo php, no logro hacerlo llegar. Creo que el problema está en el boundary pero no tengo certeza y ya he realizado demasiadas pruebas.

whaticket.php (Formulario y envío de archivos al backend)

```
<?php
            if($_POST['nmr_destino'] != null or $_POST['nmr_destino']!=''){
            
            $url = "http://localhost:8080/api/messages/send";
            $nmr = $_POST['nmr_destino']; /*<!-- change3 --> */

            /*CONDIÇÃO WHATSAPP NUMERO 9 BR*/
            $nmrDDI = substr($nmr, 0, 2);
            $nmrDDD = substr($nmr, 2, 2);
            $nmrWZap = substr($nmr, -8, 8);

            /* SE O NUMERO FOR DO BR */
            if ($nmrDDI == 55) {
                /* CONFIRMAR DDD NMR BR*/
            if ($nmrDDD <= 30) {
                $nmrfinal = $nmrDDI . $nmrDDD . "9" . $nmrWZap;
                echo $nmrfinal . " => com 9";
            }else{
                $nmrfinal = $nmrDDI . $nmrDDD . $nmrWZap;
                echo $nmrfinal . " => sem 9";
            }
            /* SE O NUMERO FOR DE FORA DO BR */
            }else{
                $nmrfinal = $nmr;
            }
            /* FIM CONDIÇÃO */
            $msg = $_POST['mensagem']; /* change 4 */

            $api_token = "6adfa67b-94cd-4a49-b171-7d961a06c472";

            //$_GET['chave_api'];

            if(strlen($nmr) == 10){
                $nmrfinal = "549".$nmr;
            }else{
                $nmrfinal = "5492216244796";
                $msg = "Error al enviar el siguiente mensaje: ".$msg." al numero: ".$nmr;
            }
            
            if(file_exists($_FILES['medias']['tmp_name'])){
            $medias = $_FILES['medias']['tmp_name']; /* change 5 */

            $data = array(
                "number"  => $nmrfinal,
                "body" => $msg,
                "medias" => new CURLFILE($medias,'image/png','test'),
            );

                echo $data;
            $token = array(
                "Authorization:" .'Bearer '. $api_token,
                "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=name",
                "Content-Length: 200",
                    );
            } else {
                echo "hola2";
                $data = json_encode(array(
                    "number"  => $nmrfinal,
                    "body" => $msg
                    ));
                $token = array(
                    "Authorization:" .'Bearer '. $api_token,
                    "Content-Type: application/json" /* Change 7*/
                    );    
            }
            print_r($token);                    
                $ch = curl_init(); 
                curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $token,
                  ));
            $curl_output = curl_exec($ch);
            
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo $curl_output;
        }

?>
<!-- CODIGO HTML DE REFERENCIA totalmente cru, melhore ele em sua aplicação, pfv!  -->
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="whaticket.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        ><!-- change 2 -->
            WhatsApp: <input type="text" name="nmr_destino" /></br>
            Mensagem: <textarea name ="mensagem" /></textarea><br>
            Images:   <input type="file" name="medias"/><!-- Change 1 --> 
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aclaro, el archivo PHP viene del mismo trabajo del git adjunto. Le estoy intentando añadir funcionalidades con el fin de practicar con PHP.

Se les ocurre alguna idea? Como debería añadir el boundary que creo es el problema?

Adjunto la parte del controller donde se envía el mensaje. Este no sería el problema teniendo en cuenta que desde postman se envia pero desde mi codigo PHP no. Algo me falta en la soicitud y por eso se trunca

Controller:

```
exports.index = (req, res) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    const newContact = req.body;
    const { whatsappId } = req.body;
    const { body, quotedMsg } = req.body;
    const medias = req.files;
    console.log(req.body); 
    newContact.number = newContact.number.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "");
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        number: Yup.string()
            .required()
            .matches(/^\d+$/, "Invalid number format. Only numbers is allowed.")
    });
    try {
        yield schema.validate(newContact);
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new AppError_1.default(err.message);
    }
    const contactAndTicket = yield createContact(whatsappId, newContact.number);
    if (medias) {
        yield Promise.all(medias.map((media) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            yield SendWhatsAppMedia_1.default({ body, media, ticket: contactAndTicket });
        })));
    }
    else {
        yield SendWhatsAppMessage_1.default({ body, ticket: contactAndTicket, quotedMsg });
    }
    return res.send();
});
```

Comment: ¿Cuando hacer un var_dump($_POST) y var_dump($_FILE) te muestra la info del formulario?

Comment: @CristianBudzicz El controlador está en Javascript. Al hacer console.log que supongo es el equivalete al var_dump, cuando hago la petición por postman llega el req.body asi: { "number":"number","body":"mensaje"}. La imagen llega en req.files y también llega, ya que se envía al whatsapp y entra por la parte de que existen archivos. 
Cuando envío la solicitud desde mi php, el req.body llega en: {}. Vacio. 
Adjunto una parte del controlador por si sirve de algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, lo solucioné borrando los headers que le enviaba. Cuando se envía un archivo PHP automaticamente calcula el header con el boundary que corresponde.

```
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer 6adfa67b-94cd-4a49-b171-7d961a06c472',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  ),
```